# Linq: How to get second last

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

So i have a List of strings that looks like this:

```
var ls=new List<string>()
    {
        "100",
        "101-102-1002",
        "105-153-1532-1532",
        "105-1854-45-198",
        "180-95-45-200"
    };
```

I want to get the second last of the the split string. So my output looks like this:

```
null,
102,
1532,
45,
45
```

I have a solution for it that looks like this:

```
ls.Select (l =>l.Split('-').Select ((s,i) =>new {s,i})
.OrderByDescending (x=>x.i).Skip(1).Take(1))
```

I think that this solution might be to complex for this simple task. So my question is: Do any of you have a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: The result is wrong or I don't get the question: shouldn't it be: null,102,153,1235?

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me!

Comment: Yes it should be the second last of the split string. If there is no second last then it should return null.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`Reverse` fits well here:

```
ls.SelectMany(l =>l.Split('-').Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty())
```

I also use `SelectMany` to transform `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` to `<IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is you would not get 'null' when splited array length is less than 2.
This is closer but not correct as this spits out Blank instead of 'null'
ls.Select(x => x.Split('-').Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: @Anand Yeah, thanks for the hint. However, I prefer my LINQ code to stay in the LINQ monad.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't get you. If `ls` is empty, then the result will be empty. If an item in `ls` is too short and does not have at least 2 components, then the result will contain `null` in place of that item. This behavior might seem however weird, but this is what the author wants, isn't it?

Comment: If you want the second to last item you need `.FirstOrDefault()` otherwise you get an `IEnumerable` of a single item, instead of that item.

Answer (score 15):

```
        var ls = new List<string>() { "100", "101-102-1002", "105-153-1532-1532", "12-1235-785" };
        var result = from p in ls
                     let arr = p.Split('-')
                     select arr.Length < 2 ? null : arr[arr.Length - 2];

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }



        Console.Read();
```

Comment: This should have been the answer. It's faster than the other one.

Answer (score 9):

If you have

`var ls = new List<string>( ... );`

then

`var result = ls.Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1);`

should work.

Answer (score 7):

```
var ls = new List<string>(){"100","101-102-1002","105-153-1532-1532","12-1235-785"}; 

var result = from l in ls
             let s = l.Split('-')
             select s.ElementAtOrDefault(s.Length - 2);
```

Comment: Does not spit out 'null' in when length is less 2 instead FirstOrDefault spits out blank.

Comment: @Anand, not sure what you mean, it does return `null` for the the first entry.

Answer (score 5):

I've created an extension based on Pavel Gatilov's answer above

```
public static TSource SecondLast<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
      //from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724179/linq-how-to-get-second-last
      return source.Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I somehow managed across this page. None of Linq answers would work. When using FirstOrDefault you have to specify DefaultIfEmpty and populate it with a value. FirstOrDefault on it's own will break if at runtime the default is required. The accepted answer had DefaultIfEmpty but doesn't specify a value. It wouldn't work, the following example will.

```
var result = ls.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ls = new List<string> { "100", "101-102-1002", "105-153-1532-1532", "12-1235-785" };
var result = ls.Select(x =>
{
    var tokens = x.Split('-');
    if (tokens.Length < 2)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return tokens[tokens.Length - 2];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In lambda syntax:

```
var ls = new List<string>() { "100", "101-102-1002", "105-153-1532-1532", "12-1235-785" };

var result = ls.Select(x => new { split = x.Split('-') }).Select(y => y.split.LastOrDefault(z => z != y.split.LastOrDefault()));
```

Comment: So you know, if you highlight your text and hit the "code" button it will format it correctly to display as a code block for you. I've gone ahead and submitted and edit for it this time.