# How do I get the object with the second latest date from a collection of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, collections

I have a list of objects and each object has an AcceptanceDate property which is of type DateTime.

I want to retrieve the Object with the second latest date in the list.

Is there any way of doing that?

```
[
   {
        "number": "X76-M1-20/2",
        "AcceptanceDate": "2020-07-30T00:00:00Z",
        "type": "Done",
    
    },

    {
        "number": "X75-M1-18/2",
        "AcceptanceDate": "2018-03-04T00:00:00Z",
        "type": "Done",
    
    },
    {
        "number": "X66-M1-20/1",
        "AcceptanceDate": "2020-02-12T00:00:00Z",
        "type": "Done",
    
    
    },
    {
        "number": "X77-M1-17/1",
        "AcceptanceDate": "2017-02-14T00:00:00Z",
        "type": "Done",
    
    } 
]
```

In This example I want to return the object with number : X66-M1-20/1

I Tried to follow this [Linq: How to get second last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724179/linq-how-to-get-second-last)

But it's not working in my case because it a list of objects.

Comment: What about you get the `list.Count - 1`? Or `list[list.Count - 1]`?

Comment: the list is not sorted.
In this case I want to get the 3rd object cause it's the second must recent one after the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json); 
var item =jd.OrderBy(j =>j.AcceptanceDate ).TakeLast(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

output

```
Number  X66-M1-20/1
AcceptanceDate  2020-02-12
Type    Done
```

class

```
public class Data
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime AcceptanceDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

Since PO wants 2 last objects I can recommend this code

```
var jd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json); 
var items =jd.Where(i=> i.Type=="Done").OrderBy(j =>j.AcceptanceDate).TakeLast(2).ToList();

if (items!= null && items.Count >=2)
{
var secondLastItem=items[0];
var lastItem=items[1];
}
```

output

```
    X66-M1-20/1 2020-02-12  Done  //secondLastItem
    X76-M1-20/2 2020-07-30  Done  //lastItem
```

Comment: Oh Sir this is great just I have a question is it possible to get the last and the second last by: Type and date ? 
Is it possible to add this condition ?

Comment: @Taieb Everything is possible, but I see the same type.  What do you mean? 4 items? two last by  type and two last by  date?

Comment: I mean to force the check for the last two recent by Date and both of them have Type : Done

Comment: @Taieb I updated my answer